# window onload call magnificpopup

Tags: javascript, magnific-popup

I have a script function its working fine in while i click a tag 
I need to call the function when site load or body load how to do this Please help me

This is the code i used

```
  <div class="html-code">
  <a href="#test-modal" class="popup-modal">Open modal</a>
            <div class="white-popup-block mfp-hide" id="test-modal">
  <span>hi</span>
   <p><a href="#" class="popup-modal-dismiss">Dismiss</a></p>
   </div>
 </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
      type: 'inline',
      preloader: true,
      focus: '#username',
      modal: true
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.popup-modal-dismiss', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.magnificPopup.close();
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to insert it into the

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... }
```

and call open() method?

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
  $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline',
    preloader: true,
    focus: '#username',
    modal: true
  }).open();
});
```